# Problem when using the ssh-copy-id command in script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, openssh

I write this for add SSH connection from the list automatically but when I run this script have error! I think this problem relate to read ip from `$line` variable in script.

**My Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

filename='iplist.txt'
n=1
USER=root
SSHPASS=123456

while read line; do
echo "No. $n : IP = $line"
echo "yes \n" | sshpass -p "$SSHPASS" \
ssh-copy-id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$line \
&& echo "Add successfully!" || echo "FAILED"

echo "########################################"
n=$((n+1))
sleep 2
done < $filename
```

**iplist.txt** is a file that's contain my IPs:

```
172.25.25.1
172.25.25.2
```

**This is the result of my script:**

```
No. 1 : IP = 172.25.25.1
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

: Name or service not known: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 172.25.25.1

FAILED
########################################

No. 2 : IP = 172.25.25.2
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

: Name or service not known: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 172.25.25.2

FAILED
########################################
```

Comment: Put a valid `shebang` in your script and paste it at https://shellcheck.net for validation/suggestions.

Comment: Avoid upper case variables, because internal/environmental variables are all upper case. Like `USER` in your example, use a different `fd` for the builtin `read` , use more quotes and more...

Comment: @Jetchisel THX, but your comments not fix my problem.

Comment: @Jetchisel if I set for example `line=172.25.25.1` my script  run successfully but it couldn't read from file!

Comment: Loks like windows to Linux issue...

Comment: Try to replace `while read line...` with `ips=( $(cat "$filename") ); for ip in ${ips[@]}; do ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. check the file endings, if they are CRLF for windows, CR for mac, or LF for linux.
2. while read -r line; do COMMAND; done
   The -r option passed to read command prevents backslash escapes from being interpreted.
   Add IFS= option before read command to prevent leading/trailing whitespace from being trimmed -
   `while IFS= read -r line; do COMMAND_on $line; done`

the code above is an example, you may want to use the -r parameter. For IFS you probably do not want to use this, because if there was any whitespace, then IFS would keep this and not remove them.